# How to parse json data from php to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a curl statement that pulls json formatted array to php. I then want to transfer this array to jQuery so that the client side will hold the array. I'm currently using the below method:

```
<script>var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( <?php echo var_dump($json_short); ?> );</script>
```

The client sees something like:

```
<script>var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( array(1) {
  ["search"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(6) "641279"
      ["description"]=>
      string(36) "Instyle - Responsive Portfolio Theme"
      ["url"]=>
      string(69) "http://themeforest.net/item/instyle-responsive-portfolio-theme/641279"
      ["type"]=>
      string(9) "wordpress"
      ["sales"]=>
      string(3) "135"
      ["rating"]=>
      string(3) "4.5"
    }
    ....
  }
}
 );</script>
```

Will obj now hold the array? is this the right way becuase I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` expect parameter to be a string.

Comment: Although your question is a lil confusing, i believe you should use print_r instead of var_dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function already, you should use that.

Would look like:

```
<script>
var a = <?php echo json_encode($json_short); ?>;

</script>
```

Comment: You would need quotes around this for it to store as a string.

Comment: That is true, but he does not want to have a string. He wants a native object or array, hence the proposed use of parseJSON() in order to convert from string to usable object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a direct dump, you need to json_encode first:

`<script>var obj = <?php echo json_encode($json_short) ?>;</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying with `<script>var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( <?php echo var_dump($json_short); ?> );</script>`

in PHP try `echo json_encode($json_short);`

Answer (score 0):

the `var_dump` function doesn't dump it as a json object.

use `json_encode` instead of `var_dump`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use var_dump first off. Next make sure you have converted your variable to a json array you have a normal array.

```
<script>var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( <?php echo json_encode($json_short); ?> );</script>
```

Comment: he shouldn't even need to use parseJSON. That takes a string and turns it into an array or obj or whatever. If json_encode is used, the data is immediately usable in javascript.

Comment: Only if he wants to use it as a string if he actually wants to be able to access the data like `obj.search[0].id` then he would need to parse it.

Comment: Also if he just wants to store it as a string then `'` or `"` would need to go around it.

Comment: He would have to parseJSON if he has a string. Using json_encode allows him to skip that step since it will be placed in javascript as a usable object.